# Estou recebendo este erro ao tornar minha Struct do tipo codable

Tags: ios, swift

Estou recebendo este erro ao tornar minha Struct do tipo codable.

Minha Struct está assim:

```swift
    struct PeripheralModel: Codable {
          let name: String
          let uuid: String
          let rssi: String
          let peripheral: CBPeripheral
    
          init(name: String, uuid: String, rssi: String, peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
              let rssi = rssi
                  .replacingOccurrences(of: "[", with: "")
                  .replacingOccurrences(of: "]", with: "")
              self.name = name
              self.uuid = uuid
              self.rssi = rssi
              self.peripheral = peripheral
          }
    }
```

Descrição do erro: Type 'PeripheralModel' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'

[print error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dI2X5.png)

Comment: For English questions, please, use [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: @dcm50 esqueci que estava no stackoverflow pt :s, ajustei. Obrigado por avisar!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Para uma classe conformar à **Codable** ela deve conformar à Encodable e Decodable ao mesmo tempo, como diz a [documentação](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable). Para ela conformar automaticamente, todas as variáveis que você declarar dentro dela devem ter conformação com **Codable**.

No seu exemplo específico, a classe `CBPeripheral` não tem conformidade com **Codable**. Então para que sua classe conforme com Codable, você deve declarar regras específicas para como sua classe irá "Encodar" e "Decodar" os seus valores.

Essa [parte específica da documentação](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types#:%7E:text=Encode%20and%20Decode%20Manually) te dá um bom caminho para fazer isso.

Comment: Obrigado Tiago, resolvi conforme a documentação